# Double Jump Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to make a 2D platformer game in Unity 2D and I'd like a system where my player can do a double jump, so he can jump and jump once more in the air, but can't jump anymore than that until hes landed back down, and i have no idea how to do this

Comment: Could you provide the Code you already have tried? Then its better to show what uve done right or wrong.

Comment: There's tons of tutorials on youtube such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEGEEZmfTT0), have you given them a shot?

Comment: i havent really tried any code, but i was thinking it could be done with a "can jump" bool, so when im on the ground "can jump" would be true and when ive jumped and doubled jumped "can jump" could be set to false, and if "can jump" is false i cant jump until ive landed, which "can jump" is then set back to true, i might be able to do that but i dont know how to tell the game to not allow me to jump, all of that might of sounded a little confusing but thats the best i can explain it

Answer (score 2):

*emphasized text*There are a lot of ways to implement the "double jump" feature. The most straight forward would be this one:

```
public int maxJumps = 2;

private int jumps;
private float jumpForce = 5f;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        this.Jump ();
    }
}

private void Jump()
{
    if (jumps > 0)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        grounded = false;
        jumps = jumps - 1;
    }
    if (jumps == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider)
{
    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        jumps = maxJumps;
        grounded = true;
        movespeed = 2.0F;                                                            
     }                                                                                
 }
```

Note that you could have another bool field in order to check if the player has already jumped twice, but using an integer gives you a more flexible solution in case you want to change the game design in the future (ex: letting the user jump three times when using a power-up).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree with you but maybe you should check your grounded bool before the first jump ? Because I think if you fall off a platform with jump > 0 you'll be able to jump. Plus it make sense to give a purpose to the grounded boolean, right ? Have a nice day !

Comment: You are right! I think it's a game design choice, I have played games where you can exploit this kind of behavior! I just wrote what I had on the top of my head, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try this code, just want my idea to be understood :

```
int nbJumps = 0;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && nbJumps < 2)
    {
        //jump here
        nbJumps++;
    }

    if (playerCollider.IsTouching(groundCollider))
    {
        nbJumps = 0;
    }
}
```